# Boundary map in Mayer-Vietoris sequence of cohomology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, cohomology, 3-manifolds

Suppose $M$ is a 3-manifold with connected boundary. Let $T$ be a tangle in $M$, i.e., $T$ is a embedded connected 1-submanifold whose boundary is on $\partial M$ ($T$ is not closed). Moreover, suppose $T$ represents a torsion element in $H_1(M,\partial M;\mathbb{Z})$. Suppose $M_T=M-T$ is the tangle complement. Consider the boundary map $\delta_*:H^1(M_T\cap N(T);\mathbb{Z})\to H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})$ from the Mayer-Vietoris sequence associated to $(M,M_T,N(T))$. We have $H^1(M_T\cap N(T);\mathbb{Z})\cong H^1(S^1\times I;\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}$. What's the image of $\delta_*$? I guess it is generated by the Lefschetz (Poincare) duality of $[T]\in H_1(M,\partial M;\mathbb{Z})\cong H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to take $M_T = M\smallsetminus T$? With your definition, $M_T\cap N_T = \emptyset$; moreover, your formula is wrong for $T$ closed (which seems to be allowed). Anyway, your cohomology class is dual to the Borel-Moore cohomology class of a two-dimensional strip along $T$, which the Mayer-Vietoris boundary operator sends to its "outer boundary", which is homologous to $T$.

Comment: @Faniel, note that two classes are naturally pull-backs from one point compactification of tubular neighborhood, i.e. everything reduces to the Thom space case and identity, you are looking for, between MV boundary and the Thom class becomes true for any oriented submanifold $T$.

Comment: @Bertram, I fix the statement. Are you indicating that my argument is true if $T$ has boundary and $M_T=M-T$? When you mention  "Borel-Moore cohomology class", do you mean homology class? It seems that a strip represents a homology class. Thanks for your answering.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I did mean homology (Borel-Moore just means that you take locally finite sums of simplices, so that it's always dual to cohomology). This is essentially the same as the Thom space argument in Bad English's answer.

Comment: @Bertram, could you provide some references about your arguments? I don't know why the dual of the cohomology class is the strip and why the boundary map sends the strip to the outer boundary. Does the outer boundary lie in $H_1^{BM}(M)$ or $H_1(M,\partial M)$?

Comment: @Bad English, could you explain more about the "pull-backs" fact? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Faniel, if you define the boundary map 
through extensions onto $N(T)$ and $M-T$ you can 
assume that an extension to $M-T$ rapidly decay, 
i.e. is equal to zero on simplices outside of $N'(T)\subset N(T)$, 
this means that the boundary operator associated with 
$M-N'(T)\to M\to M/M-N'(T)=:Th(T)$ does the same job and 
hence your boundary class in MV is equal to that in $H^*(Th(T))=H_c^*(NT)$.

Comment: On the other hand the Poincare dual of the class represented by the 
submanifold $T$ 
is the pull-back from $Th(T)$ of the Thom's class. On the level of 
$Th(T)$ they are equal, because both have the same restriction on n-disk 
"fibers", where the statement becomes the suspension isomorphism 
$H^*(S^{n-1})\to H^*(S^n)$, where in your case $n=2$. Everything here works for 
generalized cohomology as well.